# Adding image views in linearlayout programmatically but not shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding multiple image views in Linear Layout. These views are adding and also linear layout size is increasing but these views are not shown.

Here is my code:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++)
{
    Item item = itemList.get(i);

    int xCoord = (int) Utils.getPosition(resizedValues.originalWidth, resizedWidth, hotSpot.getPositionX(), context);
    int yCoord = (int) Utils.getPosition(resizedValues.originalHeight, resizedHeight, hotSpot.getPositionY(), context);

    Utils.print("xCoord = " + xCoord + " : yCoord = " + yCoord);


    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotspot);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = xCoord;
    params.topMargin = yCoord;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    Utils.print("params.leftMargin = " + params.leftMargin + " : params.topMargin = " + params.topMargin);

    Utils.print("child count = " + parentLayout.getChildCount());
    parentLayout.addView(imageView, i);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited my question, may be you get idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Scrollview as a parent of your parentLayout, just take out the frameLayout and add  a scrollviewHorizonatal instead. I hope this help you.(not too late).